# Unused variable warning in objective c

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings, unused-variables

I'm trying to learn objective-c and have encountered a warning in this example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])

{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableDictionary *booklisting = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        int count; // < Am getting 'unused variable' warning here 

        [booklisting setObject:@"Wind in the Willows" forKey:@"100-432112"];
        [booklisting setObject:@"Tale of Two Cities" forKey:@"200-532874"];
        [booklisting setObject:@"Sense and Sensibility" forKey:@"200-546549"];

        [booklisting setObject:@"Shutter Island" forKey:@"104-109834"];


       NSLog(@"Number of books in dictionary = %lu", [booklisting count]);
```

would anyone know why?.. Would appreciate help..thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are not using  any where in your code.that's why warning comes like this.

```
int count;// count is an variable  and
[booklisting count]//here count is a property of NSArray reference class
```

remove `int count;` and check it.

Comment: + 1, but `[booklisting count]` is in this case a method of `NSDictionary` ;)

Comment: yes Exactly for both aray and dictinary classes having the property count.

Comment: Yeah, but monkeyboy is using an `NSMutableDictionary` and not an `NSArray` and so your comment `//here count is a property of NSArray reference class` is wrong in this case ;)

Comment: NSMutableArray is subclass to NSArray na.

Comment: Of course it is, but we are not talking about `NSArray` at all, but **`NSDictionary`** (and **`NSMutableDictionary`**).

Comment: i agree with you regarding this question.

Answer (score 1):

you arent using `count`... `[booklisting count]` is accessing a method of `booklisting` which is a `NSMutableDictionary` which has a method called `count` which returns how many entries are in the dictionary.

its coincidence that they have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
count =[booklisting count];
```

before NSLog

or remove this `int count;` line

count is getter method for array.

Comment: Thanks.. I commented out the int count line and it worked. I'm a bit confused though. The code that I used is exactly the same as instructed from an ebook called "Objective-C 2.0 Essentials" by Neil Smyth. I got it from techtopia.com – how could he be wrong? Or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `int count;` since you have not used variable `count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count; // < Am getting 'unused variable' warning here
```

You declare a variable count.But it is **never used**.Hence the error is shown